# excel Delete Row #reference error in formula

Tags: excel

Could someone tell me if right now there is some way to prevent #reference error in formula in one sheet when i want to delete row in another sheet (formula contains a reference on a cell in that sheet). ps. I do not want to use indirect function because it is volatile.

thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'prevent'? Do you just want a different message? If so, use the `IFERROR` function.

Comment: I mean, if i delete, for example, row 3, cell with formula on another sheet  which before deletion had reference on cell C3, after row deletion would still contain formula with adress of cell C3, not #reference error.

Comment: Do you really need to delete this cell? Could you store the cell address elsewhere and use that (I know you said you don't want to use `INDIRECT`)?